# Passport.js Authentication within Express.js seems to be broken after implementing db connection pooling

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, connection-pooling, passport-local

Really confuse why my app login behaviour seems to be weird after i implemented pooling. Everything was fine when i use createConnection() instead of createPool() method inside my db configuration. The "weird" behaviour appears when i clear all of the session that stored in database( I use mysql store to impelement persistent session). The weird behavior is: It redirects back to login page even if i have filled the form correctly and submit it. When i try to refresh the page (pressing F5), it's finally redirect me to the correct page (home). The problem also appears in logout. When i press log out button, the session is destroyed, but it redirects me to home page instead of login. Everything was fine when i didn't use pooling.
Here's my auth controller:

index.js (controller)

```
var session = require('express-session');
var flash = require('connect-flash');
var passport = require('passport');
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
//config
var pool = require('../config/db.js');

//serialize and deserialize passport
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    console.log('user serialized');
    done(null, user.username);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(username, done) {
    pool.query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = ?", [username], function(err, rows, fields) {
        console.log('deserialized');
        done(err, rows[0]);
    });
});

passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
    passReqToCallback: true
}, function(req, username, password, done) {
    pool.query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = ?",[username], function(err, rows, fields) {
        if (err) throw err;
        if (!rows[0]) {
            return done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'Oops! Wrong username.'));
        }
        if (!bcrypt.compareSync(password, rows[0].password)) {
            return done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'Oops! Wrong password.'));
        }
        return done(null, rows[0]);
    });
}));

module.exports.login_get = function(req, res, next) {
    if(req.isAuthenticated()){
        var sql = "SELECT * FROM venue";
        pool.query(sql, function(err, rows, fields){
        res.render('index/home', {person:req.user, venues:rows});
        });
    }
    else{
        res.render('index/login');
    }
}

module.exports.login_post = passport.authenticate('local', {
    successRedirect: '/',
    failureRedirect: '/',
    failureFlash: true
});

module.exports.logout_get = function(req, res) {
    req.logout();
    res.redirect('/');
};
```

index.js(routes)

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

//load controller
var index = require('../controllers/index');

//load auth middleware
var auth = require('../controllers/auth_middleware');

//route level middleware
router.get('/', index.login_get);
router.post('/', index.login_post);
router.get('/logout', auth.isLoggedIn, index.logout_get);

module.exports = router;
```

db.js (configuration)

```
var mysql = require('mysql'); 

var dbConnectionInfo = {
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: '',
    database: 'me',
    connectionLimit: 10, //set connectionLimit for pooling
};
//create pool
var pool = mysql.createPool(dbConnectionInfo);

pool.on('connection', function (connection) {
    console.log('DB Connection established');
    connection.on('error', function (err) {
      console.error(new Date(), 'MySQL error', err.code);
    });
    connection.on('close', function (err) {
      console.error(new Date(), 'MySQL close', err);
    });

  });

module.exports = pool;
```

auth.middleware.js

```
 module.exports.isLoggedIn = function(req, res, next){
          if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
            return next()
          }
          else{
            res.redirect('/');
          }
      }

    module.exports.isSuperAdmin = function(req, res, next){
      if(req.user.role === "superadmin"){
        return next();
      }
      else{
        res.redirect('/');
      }
    }
```

I wrote console.log inside serialize and deserialize method. When i first log in user is serialized and NOT deserialized. When i refresh the page with f5, user is finally deserialized and i'm redirected to the home page. Why the deserialize mthod is not executed?

Comment: is it easy enough to revert back to non-pool to see if it really is just db related?

Comment: have you tried some basic queries using the pool (not using login/auth) just to see if your pool is working and it's just the login part that is broken?

Comment: others query works fine. All fiture works well except the auth. I dont really know what to do

Comment: yes it is. I just need to change createPool to createConnection. I did it. It works well

Comment: The problem is the deserialize method is not executed when i logged in.